# php file uploading in background?

Tags: php

I am following this tutorial to upload a file using php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Using this, I have to refresh the page or redirect it, is there a way I can just upload it in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean... At the point this script runs, the upload has already completed

Comment: Yea, but the form directs to <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"> before this runs.

Comment: Pekka is right, the script doesn't even run until the file has been uploaded. If I'm understanding the question correctly then you'll probably want to use AJAX to upload the file and read the response.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 2):

Do as all the other scripts. Create a hidden iframe, set a target on your form to that iframe and your good to.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using jquery uploads plugins? You can find plenty of them and they doing a wonderful work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of scripts out there to help with file uploads.

Some examples:

- http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php
- http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Just do a google search or two!

But you will need some javascript knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, to read and write your requests and responses. Search on XMLHttp Requests and that may help. You can do a POST operation there.